# Dell OS and Support Software CD

Tags: dell-studio

I have Dell 17 studio laptop and bought at march 2009 . But now i lost the all CD Pack of operating system and software .

How to get another copy of  those from dell  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot download those online from Dell, even with your service tag (but take a look around the support downloads). Try calling Dell Customer Service. It's probably the ONLY reason to actually buy a Dell in the first place. Amazing service... They'll no doubt send you a new one.

Comment: I contacted Dell a couple months ago on a similar issue. Couldn't locate the restore CDs for a 3 year old machine (suspect it never came with them, but we had killed the restore partition on day 1). Dell sent out a CD set Next-Day for free.